# How to correctly handle the case where iteration on a single element causes an error to be thrown?

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch

I have some code that decomposes a wave into it's component frequencies, and plots those components. Here is the plotting method:

```
    def plot_components(self):
        try:
            N = self.rate * self.time
            t_vec = np.arange(N) * self.period

            fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(self.components), 1)
            for i, wave in enumerate(self.components):
                axes[i].plot(t_vec, wave)
            plt.xlabel('Time')
            plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
            plt.show()
        except ValueError:
            print('plt_components: Encoder must be fit against composite wave before plotting')
            raise
```

This works fine if multiple wave components are returned. Sometimes, either the wave doesn't have any components except itself, or some times the algorithm can only identify a single component. In that case, a singleton wave makes up the list of components and I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable
```

I thought about handling this with another `except` statement:

```
except TypeError:
   axes.plot(t_vec, self.components[0])
   plt.show()
```

And this does work. However, I'm unsure if this is proper use of error handling? I'm a bit new to the idea of stopping/handling errors and want to know if what I did is okay in practice.

I guess my nervousness comes from wondering "What if another `TypeError` is thrown for a reason I didn't expect?"

Comment: What causes the `TypeError`?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica The fact that I subscript the `axes` object when it is not subscriptable because it is a single axes object rather than a list of axes objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a small check after the plt.subplots line:

```py
if len(self.components) == 1:
    axes = [axes]
```

In general, there is the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html) coding guideline, programming for happy flow and catching exceptions is a valid coding style. You could wrap only the offending line in the try-except block if you are worried.

Comment: Oh cool! Easier to ask permission than forgiveness! That's awesome, thank you for turning me on to this guideline.

Comment: You got it the other way around :) However in this specific case I think I would go with the if check before as it is just as short and exceptions do induce overhead

Comment: Hah! Yeah, I just read about LBYL in that link. Any reason to not mix and match LBYL and EAFP as I see fit?

Comment: I think that's the best way to go. Whatever works best for your code flow.